# How to use showcase plugin for first string in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, showcaseview, feature-discovery

I want to use a showcase widget on a text
displayed after a result is run.
This is the implementation
[image]

I want to implement this feature for the first string of the map.
when I execute it like this. The text seems to disappear.
How to fix this.
for example, if the map has three strings I want the showcase widget to appear on the first string only.

Comment: Please don't post screenshot/photo of the code instead copy and paste the entire code [reason](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep your current logic, with a `map` on your list of Objects in order to return a list of `Widgets`, your only solution is to create a variable which you'll use as an index.

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var index = 0;

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(children: e.phonetics.map((e){
          index++;
          if (index == 1) {
            return //Your Widget with the ShowCase
          } else {
            return //Your Widget without the ShowCase
          }
        }).toList()),
      ),
    );
  }
```